# Move just the phone number box of intl-tel-input

Tags: css, angular

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-tel-input and having problems with the layout of the input itself.

Currently the flag dropdown is being overlayed on top of the input box causing visual problems [image]

I would like my input to be moved to the right a bit, but I just cant seem to get my css to apply as it keeps defaulting to the package css.

I can successfully move it to where I want via Inspect Element by adding some margin to the input itself [image] but even when I copy the rule and place it in my css file it doesn't get applied, with and without `!important`

Here is the html and css for my intl-tel-input

```
<intl-tel-input
  [name]="'phoneInput'"
  [required]="true"
  [options]="{
    preferredCountries: ['GB'],
    onlyCountries: ['GB', 'US', 'IE']
  }"
  [onlyLocalized]="true"
  [(E164PhoneNumber)]="E164PhoneNumber">
</intl-tel-input>

:host ::ng-deep .iti {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

--not being applied

```
.iti--allow-dropdown input, .iti--allow-dropdown input[type=text], .iti--allow-dropdown input[type=tel], .iti--separate-dial-code input, .iti--separate-dial-code input[type=text], .iti--separate-dial-code input[type=tel] {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 52px;
  margin-left: 10% !important;
}
```

and the computed html for the intl-tel-input

```
<intl-tel-input _ngcontent-xka-c95="" _nghost-xka-c93="" ng-reflect-name="phoneInput" ng-reflect-required="true" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-only-localized="true" ng-reflect--e164-phone-number="">
   <!--bindings={}-->
   <div class="iti iti--allow-dropdown">
      <div class="iti__flag-container">
         <div class="iti__selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-controls="iti-0__country-listbox" aria-owns="iti-0__country-listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" title="United Kingdom: +44" aria-activedescendant="iti-0__item-gb-preferred">
            <div class="iti__flag iti__gb"></div>
            <div class="iti__arrow"></div>
         </div>
         <ul class="iti__country-list iti__hide" id="iti-0__country-listbox" role="listbox" aria-label="List of countries">
            <li class="iti__country iti__preferred iti__active" tabindex="-1" id="iti-0__item-gb-preferred" role="option" data-dial-code="44" data-country-code="gb" aria-selected="true">
               <div class="iti__flag-box">
                  <div class="iti__flag iti__gb"></div>
               </div>
               <span class="iti__country-name">United Kingdom</span><span class="iti__dial-code">+44</span>
            </li>
            <li class="iti__divider" role="separator" aria-disabled="true"></li>
            <li class="iti__country iti__standard" tabindex="-1" id="iti-0__item-ie" role="option" data-dial-code="353" data-country-code="ie" aria-selected="false">
               <div class="iti__flag-box">
                  <div class="iti__flag iti__ie"></div>
               </div>
               <span class="iti__country-name">Ireland</span><span class="iti__dial-code">+353</span>
            </li>
            <li class="iti__country iti__standard" tabindex="-1" id="iti-0__item-gb" role="option" data-dial-code="44" data-country-code="gb" aria-selected="false">
               <div class="iti__flag-box">
                  <div class="iti__flag iti__gb"></div>
               </div>
               <span class="iti__country-name">United Kingdom</span><span class="iti__dial-code">+44</span>
            </li>
            <li class="iti__country iti__standard" tabindex="-1" id="iti-0__item-us" role="option" data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us" aria-selected="false">
               <div class="iti__flag-box">
                  <div class="iti__flag iti__us"></div>
               </div>
               <span class="iti__country-name">United States</span><span class="iti__dial-code">+1</span>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <input _ngcontent-xka-c93="" type="text" ng-reflect-name="phoneInput" ng-reflect-required="true" id="phoneInput" name="phoneInput" aria-required="true" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="07400 123456" data-intl-tel-input-id="0">
   </div>
</intl-tel-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use `::ng-deep` as well as an ID identifier in the css, so it looks like this:

```
::ng-deep input#phoneInput {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```